# How to set the values in session?

Tags: java, servlets, struts2, struts, httpsession

If I'm getting empty session I need to setup some values to play the action class. So, here is the method

```
public SearchFilters getFilters() {
 return (SearchFilters) getSession().get("Filters");
}
```

I would like to check the session, if it's `null`, then I need to set the some values over here.

```
public SearchFilters getFilters() {
if(getSession().get("Filters").equals(null)){
---- //How to set the values and return ?
}
 return (SearchFilters) getSession().get("Filters");
}
```

Comment: So what is the return type of your getSession. are you mean HttpSession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code:

```
public SearchFilters getFilters() {
if(getSession().get("Filters") == null){
  //How to set the values
  getSession().put("Filters", new Filters()); 
}
// and return.
 return (SearchFilters) getSession().get("Filters");
}
```

assumed you have injected the session into the action via implementing `SessionAware`.

The value is a free hand object which contains no value, but you could create a constructor to it and pass the value directly.

Answer (score 0):

`getSession()` will return a new session if an existing session is not found. So you don't need to worry about this one ever returning **null**. Take note though, there's no `get()` method under HttpSession, it's `getAttribute()`.

So you can do this:

```
public SearchFilters getFilters() {

    if(getSession().getAttribute("Filters") == null) {
         getSession().setAttribute("Filters", new SearchFilters());
    }

    return (SearchFilters) getSession().getAttribute("Filters");
}
```

Comment: If OP is using SessionAware the session is a map, not an HttpSession. OP didn't provide enough details.

Comment: Good point Dave, missed that. Anyway the other answer has that covered. Thank you.