# Struts2 - How to bind back the value to POJO which is rendered through <s:property> on jsp page

Tags: html, forms, jsp, struts2, javabeans

I am working on Struts 2 and displaying a POJO/bean property value onto the JSP through `<s:property>` tag.

But when I submit back to the action, I am not getting this value binded to POJO.

```
<s:property value="name" />
```

I am getting the values of editable fields(ex: text field) back onto the action, but non-editable values are not binding back to the pojo.

At present I am using `<s:hidden name="name" />` tag to bind back the data to pojo.

I am implementing the `ModelDriven` interface to action class.

But is there any other way to bind the non-editable values back onto pojo?

---

Actually i have a "List" of objects in the form, which i am iterating in jsp and displaying the values using  and  tags as per my requirement.

When i submit the form, i am navigating to another action class(which is using the same form bean/pojo) and here i am getting the values of only textfields but not those which are displayed with  tag.

To get those values i am using the  tag.

But is there any way to bind the form values back to pojo using `<s:property>`? Please Suggest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.
too broad

Comment: @Roman C, please find more details added to question and suggest.

Comment: Suggested, take care to accept and upvote my answer. The help will be rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values that are rendered via `s:property` tag doesn't need to submit to the action because these values never change. Between requests the session scope is available to the action. So you won't carry them all in JSP with hidden fields. Hope you know how to implement a session map with your actions. Put the values to the session and forget about passing them to the action.

I found that many scopes are available to you. Lets look at [all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32401791/573032) of them.

Now you have to learn a little bit about session map from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14651614/573032) answer.

And finally you learn [how to put values into session map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17392336/573032).

A lot of more answers related to this topic could be extracted but you can find all of them in my answers.

Answer (score 0):

In Struts2 action extens the class `ActionServlet` and create variable of POJO.

```
public SomeAction extends ActionServlet{

    private POJO yourPOJOVariable;

    //Now create getters and setters because they will bind this to it.
    public POJO getYourPOJOVariable() {
     return name;
     }
    //execute method and so on   

}
```

Don't forget in JSP to use that variable in property tag

```
  <s:property value="yourPOJOVariable.classvariable"/>
```

Also use camel casing to variables.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

`<s:property />` will generate text. Text is not sent to the server, only form fields are.

#### Solution

Use an hidden field in conjunction with every `<s:property />` you want to send back, either generating it through the `<s:hidden />` tag or manually with `<input type="hidden" />`:

```xml
<s:property value="foo" />
<s:hidden    name="foo" />

<s:textfield name="bar" />
```